# Eclipse-pydev, while trying to import sqlite3 im getting "Undefined variable from import: connect"

Tags: python, eclipse, sqlite, pydev

Eclipse version : Version: 3.8.1

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.connect('database.db')
print "Database connected successfully"
```

in the above code, `sqlite3.connect()` is displayed as

```
Undefined variable from import: connect
```

But when i run the code it is running properly, why is that it is displayed as Error in eclipse-pydev?

Comment: You can override it like this: `sqlite3.connect('database.db') # @UndefinedVariable`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2248987 for more info.

Comment: Thanks cryptochronoconolite.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the similar issue, solution is -->

You need to add 'sqlite3' (without the quotatios) in the 'forced builtins' tab in Window>Preferences>PyDev>Python Interpreter

check this link for details
[Python: Unresolved import error for sqlite3 in PyDev in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407970/python-unresolved-import-error-for-sqlite3-in-pydev-in-eclipse)

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).