# sqlite3 - undefined variable from import python error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pydev

I am having a problem with this piece of code that produces the error below

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
```

Error:

```
Undefined variable from import: connect
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong since the code is almost completely identical to the sample in the documentation.

Comment: Is that the exact code snippet that was producing the error? When I tried it, I had no issues connecting.

Comment: @JakeConway . Yes.

Comment: Looks like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372479/eclipse-pydev-while-trying-to-import-sqlite3-im-getting-undefined-variable-fro